Suggestion for better proof writing involving many short equations

Starting to use LaTeX for proof-writing and being much used to the traditional proof-writing on pen and paper, I kind of feel irritated in a certain way when the proof, as to how I would usually write in my notebook, does not appear in the way I want in LaTeX.
Here, in particular, I needed suggestions for the proofs, especially of the kinds where the words are minimal and equations are smaller in width as well, i.e. the proofs here comprise A \implies B \implies C and so on with the width of A, B, C being small, can this be represented in a neater manner than I did?
What sets me off is the width \quad produces and vertical spacing between the equations with less appeal, again in terms of spacing as opposed to how I would write it in my book.
I found a LaTeX proof written of the same here, but I want a type having minimal words; using A \implies B \implies C scheme as mentioned.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Ex}[chapter]
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}

\newcommand{\bR}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}

\title{Real Analysis}
\author{Naman Thakkar}
\date{Nov 2024}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Real Numbers}
\section{Dedekind Cut (Pugh, Ch-2)}
The set $\mathbb{Q}$ is incomplete.
\begin{theorem}
    $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$.
\begin{proof}
Assume $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$.\\
$\exists r \in \mathbb{Q}, \quad r = p/q \quad \textrm{s.t.} \quad p/q = \sqrt{2}, \quad \textrm{with} \quad(p,q) = 1$ \\
$\textrm{Squaring both sides, we get}$, \\
$p^2 = 2q^2 \implies 2 \mid p^2 \implies 2 \mid p,$ \\
$\textrm{Hence}, \ p = 2k,\ k \in \mathbb{Z} \implies p^2 = 4k^2$\\
$\textrm{Now}, \ 4k^2 = 2q^2 \implies q^2 = 2k^2 \implies 2 \mid q^2 \implies 2 \mid q$, \\
$\textrm{Since}, \ 2 \mid p \ \textrm{and} \ 2 \mid q \implies 2 \mid (p,q) \implies 2 \mid 1$, \\
$\textrm{Hence, a contradiction}$.
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}

EDIT - Yup, after all the suggestions, it was all about writing it in simple sentences. It turns out that A \implies B \implies C, and so on. The computer-ish way of writing ain't not just philosophically but also typographically less effective.

Using double backslashes in text is never the solution as far as I understand. Perhaps just writing a complete paragraph in simple sentences is the way to go.

@mickep I understand that is a simple solution, but I want things to be short and neat here. Could there be a way to make it better readable? Proof directly in the form of A \implies B \implies C, and so on.

Well, I just mean that. A paragraph with simple sentences: Assume, to get a contradiction, that \(\sqrt{2}\) is rational, say \(\sqrt{2} = p/q\) where \(p\) and \(q\) are relative prime. .... I think that will be easier to read. Also, you introduce unnecessary notation. Your r is not really needed.

I would definitely only put $...$ aound math expression and leave the text in text mode.  For one thing, it adds a little space each time you switch.

There is no way to improve this style. Use words: you're teaching/learning mathematics, not to jot down symbols.
